# Proper method for switching through Jquery pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages. One contains a list of teachers. Selecting a teacher from the list bring you to the second page where I would like to dynamically create of list of their students from the result of my ajax call.  My problem is general confusion from contradicting information on the internet so I can not figure out how to call a function upon changing pages.

I have tried using pageshow, pageinit, pagebeforeshow, pagecreate and a couple more along those lines. The first part of my problem is that I do not know which is the correct method, because at various places of the internet someone said each of those was right but I could not find an explanation why.

The second part of my problem is I do not know which selector and/or method. The document or the page? and to use bind, delegate, live or on. So I've been going at this for a while so if someone could help me understand what solution would best fit my appreciate it.

Comment: @mplungjan you are saying only have one data-role="page"?

Comment: I've came across that a few hours ago. I can not remember what about that did not fit my solution, but I will try it again and provide feedback

Comment: HERE is the documentation http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH11.php

Comment: yeah that has been throwing me off as well. One method I saw that I also could not get to work that you may have some insight on was calling page transition animations with a function as a callback.